# Backup MySQL DB along with CarrierWave uploads stored in S3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, backup, carrierwave

In Rails app I would like to take backups of MySQL database along with CarrierWave uploads stored in Amazon S3. I have looked into S3 object versioning but couldn't find any support in CarrierWave for it.

Has anyone done this before? Or any ideas?

Comment: You can take the mysql backup as this: `mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]`. And for the Amazon S3 uploads it saves the image or upload file name in the database which connects to the folder/bucket given in the configuration of S3 in rails. So taking a normal backup should work but I am not sure. But you can give it a try.

Comment: In my case the image names will be same for updated images. So, the images will be overwritten in S3. I guess it won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  def filename
    return unless original_filename

    if model && model.read_attribute(mounted_as).present? && model.changed.blank?
      model.read_attribute(mounted_as)

    else
     ext = File.extname(original_filename)
     base = File.basename(original_filename, ext)

     "#{base}_#{token}#{ext}"
    end
  end

  # override method to avoid deletion of file
  def remove!; end

protected
  def token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end
```

I have used this approach to create unique filename every time a file is uploaded hence avoid the possibility of overwriting the previous file with same name. Also, I have configured CarrierWave not to remove previously stored files on update. So, now if I restore a DB backup, the images will be there.

Snippet inspired from [create random and unique filenames](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files).